# URL Rewrite and Redirect rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need help in URL rewriting of my own. My URL structure is looks like

http://domain.com/products-details.php?id=14

What i want it to be something like http://domain.com/products/14/

**What i have tried so far** is this in my .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /myproject/notfound.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myproject/

RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)$ products-detail.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

The above rule works fine without the trailing slash at the end, but i do want the slash at the end.

**Further more:**

It would be great if the non-rewrite request gets redirected to the rewrite ones. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new rule for redirect:

ErrorDocument 404 /myproject/notfound.php

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myproject/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /products-detail\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ products/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/?$ products-detail.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Awesome, real quick fix.